# Unity Firebase database GetValueAsync() returning null

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, null

This started to happen after I updated from 5.0.0 to 5.2.1, but it also happens on 5.1.0, before it was enough with:

```c#
if (task.Result.Exist){}
```

But now I have to do:

```c#
if (task.Result != null && task.Result.Exist){}
```

because somehow task.Result may be null, is that okay?

I tested with this piece of code:

```c#
DatabaseRoot.Child("users").Child(userId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Firebase task error: " + task.Exception.Message);
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        Debug.Log("Task completed.");
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Result " + (task.Result == null));
            Debug.Log("Result " + task.Result.Exists);
            Debug.Log("Result " + task.Result.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
});
```

It works well (as it used to be) if I return to the 5.0.0, but I need some of the patches in the newer versions.

Comment: Is it a problem to add that `null` check? It won't break the old version and if it works after that than why not using it?

Comment: I have to use it now, it just seems wrong since it is an agreement that DataSnapshot will never be null.

Comment: My app also breaks after upgrading